# Ionic login with facebook with application, not with safari or web browser from mobile app

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I have an app login with facebook feature and it uses 'phonegap-facebook-plugin',
but everytime even the phone has facebook it opens browser to authenticate user to my mobile app. How can I solve this?

I use this syntax;

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email', 'public_profile'], fbLoginSuccess, fbLoginError);
```

Any offers will welcome, thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you running on a simulator? Is facebook app installed on the phone?
The syntax for login is ok, Refer this link - "https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework"

Comment: Yes I demonstrated on my iPhone 5s and also facebook app is installed and logged in from settings->facebook. But it doesn't work :/